# What did i do wrong here? The 3D module is not showing up

Tags: javascript, 3d-modelling

I am trying to use three.js to open an obj 3d module, but for some reason i cannot manage to generate the module out on the web, is there anything wrong i done here? (i just directly follow this tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHuSQ7I1aKs)
My obj and mtl file is at directory "/Documents/js/bugatti" while my html file is at "/Documents/js"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "module" src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script type = "module" src="MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script type = "module">

          var scene = new THREE.Scene();

          var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
          camera.position.z = 200;

          var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
          document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

          var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
          controls.enableDamping = true;
          controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
          controls.enableZoom = true;

          var keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
          keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

          var fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
          fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

          var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
          backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

          scene.add(keyLight);
          scene.add(fillLight);
          scene.add(backLight);

          var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
          mtlLoader.setTexturePath('/Document/js/bugatti/');
          mtlLoader.setPath('/Documents/js/bugatti/');
          mtlLoader.load('bugatti.mtl', function (materials) {

              materials.preload();

              var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
              objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
              objLoader.setPath('/Documents/js/bugatti/');
              objLoader.load('bugatti.obj', function (object) {

                  scene.add(object);
                  object.position.y -= 60;

              });

          });

          var animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
          };

          animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+three.js+orbitcontrols+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I would expect "OrbitControls.js" to be AFTER three.js

Comment: Look in he console for errors.